# RegEx pattern to mark empty anchors of links

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I've got the four types of the links:

2 without anchors

```
<a href="/"><span style="color: #000000;"></span></a><br>
<a href="/"></a><br>
```

and 2 with anchors

```
<a href="/"><span style="color: #000000;">Cars</span></a><br>
<a href="/">Cars</a><br>
```

What RegEx pattern I should use to mark the 2 empty links only?

I've found the pattern

```
<a href=.*?><\/a>
```

that marks

```
<a href="/"><span style="color: #000000;">Cars</span></a>
```

that is not empty.

Comment: Using regular expressions to parse HTML, or generally XML, is usually a bad idea. You should look for a HTML parser instead.

Comment: @Paul-Etienne: Thank you for the information. Is it compatible with Excel VBA?

Comment: I think so. Take a look at [this article](https://codingislove.com/parse-html-in-excel-vba/), I think it might help you.

Comment: "Is it compatible with Excel VBA" - have you tried browsing your *add/remove project references* dialog (Tools > References) to see what type libraries could potentially be used for that? FWIW "Excel VBA" is just "VBA", there's no such thing as "Excel VBA", "Excel VBA" is just an object model, i.e. nothing more than a type library that's referenced by default in any VBA project hosted in an Excel document.

Comment: Thank you Paul-Etienne, I will study this.

Comment: Easiest that I can think of is pattern as `(<a href="\/"><span style="color: #000000;">|<a href="\/">)(<\/span><\/a>|<\/a>)` which just places them literally next to each other.

Comment: @Shrivallabha Redij: Thanks a lot for your example, but I guess there is a few types of the span tag.

Comment: Your question said 4 cases! so I assumed them to be literally. Solution by Leonhard also works!!

Comment: @Mat's Mug: Thanx, it's very useful information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex matches your link because `.*` means: everything. So it matches

```
<a href=  ["/"><span style="color: #000000;">Cars</span]  ></a>
```

This regex would be possible, but as Paul-Etienne mentioned, it is a better idea to use a HTML parser.

```
<a href=".*">(?:<\/span>)?<\/a>
```

Comment: It works with "": `<a href="".*"">(?:<\/span>)?<\/a>`

Answer (score 0):

For VBA better to use `<a href="".*"">(?:<\/span>)?<\/a>`

Comment: The (?:<span>)? is useless because it's <span ... (no right angle bracket sorry - i made the same mistake before) and you will need the " " - maybe you have to escape them with \